# Why generic Type "T extends 'a' | 'b'" is not resolved correctly when in a condition that checks if the param is equal to a value of the union type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I can simplify my code like this:

```js
function myFn<
    T extends 'a' | 'b' = any
>(
    valueType: T,
    value: T extends 'a' ? '1' : '2',
) {
    if (valueType === 'a') {
        value // value: DbType extends "a" ? "1" : "2"
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DEwB4CwAoRQxAFUQFMAPKMsAEwGdEByAQycQB9mAjdgXkQswqfAD4AFPiKIAbiwA2IMsVQAHMgC4SAGilE5izSXJUaDZm0QB+ZgEZ2WpgCYmuvAEpEAbz2EYwRHEDJRV1RD4IiyZPHwJpfQUlRAB6ZNlEowARblCyE2o6RgAiFiLrRCLbMq0ipyLfRABffGa8fHa2ztTEAEEAOQB5YgAJAFEAJRMWZFV5Mg7QSFgEFAwwJyCM3Mc2bXTDR3t3LSERPEXoeCQ0TA3g5TUjJl49+8cXY8FhfAvl67W7ltHjt2Fxnq59kpDqDmB8TsJvA1-IF7rlwpFWNFEXF4pC8t03hUqpwKnUGq1GkA)

Here, I would expect that when inside the `if (valueType === 'a')`, `value` would be interpolated as '1', since we are sure that in this case, it extends 'a' and therefore that the check for `value` type would output `T extends 'a' ? '1' : '2'` => `'1'`

Could you explain why it is not working this way ? Could you provide an alternative to get the expected type in this scenario?

Comment: See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WyjRdw) for why your assumption about `T` inside `myFn` isn't correct and how to refactor `myFn` to work as expected.  If that fully addresses the question I'll write up a full answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks good, at least it's a good alternative :) While I would prefer a more readable and extendable way, for exemple by using generic type or straight typings

Comment: "While I would prefer a more readable and extendable way, for example by using generic type or straight typings" Sorry, does that mean if I go through the effort of writing up an answer there's a chance you won't accept it because it doesn't meet your needs?  Could you elaborate how a discriminated union isn't "readable" and "extendable" so I can either address it or disengage?   What are "straight typings"?

Comment: @jcalz yes I'll accept it, thanks for the effort, it just that at first sight it seems a bit complex to read, immagining it would apply to a more complex example, I would prefer something more semantic. But I'll accept my answer, as it is totally correct  Also, I updated my playground with another example. I am also really willing to understand why it doesn't work :)

Comment: Okay, I will write up an answer when I get a chance, and hopefully it will be more intuitive to you once you read it.  EDIT: please don't expand the scope of the question further. Your new version doesn't work because overload implementations don't know anything about individual call signatures.  I consider this out of scope for the question and will not address it in my answer; if you need more info about that I'd recommend making a new post for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Generics and case analysis do not currently play nicely together**

Currently TypeScript is not able to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, like `T` inside the body of `myFn`.  The main obstacle in doing so is that when a type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `T extends "a" | "b"`, it does *not* mean that `T` will either be `"a"` or it will be `"b"`.  It is also possible for `T` to be the full union `"a" | "b"`. There's currently no way to say that `T` must be exactly *one* member of a union.  Therefore `myFn()` is callable like this:

```
myFn(Math.random() < 0.999 ? "a" : "b", "2"); // okay
// function myFn<"a" | "b">(valueType: "a" | "b", value: "1" | "2"): void
```

where `T` has been inferred as `"a" | "b"`, and since `T extends "a" ? "1" : "2"` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), it means that both `valueType` and `value` are of uncorrelated union types.  So nothing stops someone from calling `myFn()` with a `valueType` of `"a"` and a `value` of `"2"`, and indeed the above example has a 99.9% chance of doing so.

There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) to say that `T` must be exactly one member of a union. Maybe in some future version of TypeScript you could write something like

```
// NOT VALID TYPESCRIPT, DON'T TRY THIS
function myFn<T oneof 'a' | 'b'>(valueType: T, value: T extends 'a' ? '1' : '2') {
    if (valueType === 'a') {
        value // value: "1"
    }
}

myFn(Math.random() < 0.999 ? "a" : "b", "2"); // not allowed
```

but for now it's not part of the language.  Until and unless that changes, if you check a value like `valueType` of a generic type like `T`, it may have an effect on the type of `valueType`, but it will have no affect whatsoever on `T`.

---

**Case analysis and discriminated unions do play nicely together**

We can't use generics for control flow.

If you want to use control flow analysis to check the value of one variable and have it affect the apparent type of another, you will need the first variable to be a discriminant of a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), and both variables will need to be [destructured](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions).

Without destructuring, it could look like this quite standard discriminated union:

```
type AcceptableArgs =
    { valueType: "a", value: "1" } |
    { valueType: "b", value: "2" };

function myFn(arg: AcceptableArgs) {
    if (arg.valueType === 'a') {
        arg.value // "1"
    }
}
```

Here you can clearly see the relationship between `valueType` and `value`.  Either `valueType` is `"a"` and `value` is `"1"`, or `valueType` is `"b"` and `value` is `"2"`.

But presumably you don't want to pass an object to `myFn`.  Instead of making `AcceptableArgs` a plain object type, we can make it a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) corresponding to the parameter *list* of `myFn`.  That is, we will make `AcceptableArgs` the type of `myFn`'s [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
type AcceptableArgs =
    [valueType: "a", value: "1"] |
    [valueType: "b", value: "2"];

function myFn(...[valueType, value]: AcceptableArgs) {
    if (valueType === 'a') {
        value // value: "1"
    }
}
```

And we've destructured that rest parameter into the `valueType` and `value` variables, so that it behaves exactly as you want.  Alternatively it could be written as:

```
type MyFn = (...args: AcceptableArgs) => void;

const myFn: MyFn = (valueType, value) => {
    if (valueType === 'a') {
        value // value: "1"
    }
}
```

Either way, the compiler is able to follow the relationship between `valueType` and `value` enough to narrow `value` to `"1"` or `"2"` depending on the value of `valueType`.

And note, when you call the function, your IDE will present it as if it were [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), like so:

```
myFn(
//   ^-- 1/2 myFn(valueType: "a", value: "1"): void
//       2/2 myFn(valueType: "b", value: "2"): void
```

So it should hopefully be straightforward to use from the caller's side as well.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBxCwICcCW8oBEB7YAFwHVDMBrACS2QG8BYAKFaQ6QDMBXYeEtmJIwATwBiwADztOcgCpIIADxLoAJlCQByENqQAfHQCN9AXiQhgo2RwB8ACltykANxAAbHhHmiYEAC4keQAaZzl3L0DgpVUNLV19AH4dAEZ9IO0AJm0wljkASiRmfJcObC4kB0jvX38kM0adPSKSsrKa5AB6LrdPbyDFFTVgTSQAIhBxpBTx1Omg8azx8M4AX2cNtlKOMUkHAFkQEgALADpMK3VCMAciqSQABjOATjeZiamkReNxkInlgUANxIHpIN6vACkSHgJysiCQokIPEwligUB4YBggmEAHcQFpcZhiABzZxg3j8HHAEQSaSTaZGca-RydOrRBmGCa-f6dRbzLlLcYFIKuQjYdSsLasUCQWAIZAABUI6Owxg8EHEPBIKIgAEkuFkAOwADkeJr1UD1WI1kFIEHUxXJACpVhxKQIhDS9tJFMQIIRKokudpTI43S42X5oqEIxF+jHYiMxsGUtp0t8dDk8u0kK045wKlUo-VGhZEvmdrnIwnQb0+RN5gWOFtc63OBGfYdjudLqMbnckA9nm8Xh9OT8-gDhSCwcBCCRLB4PIRcQ6I86ulLWDuWLLoHAEfhsFB4DgwNhQGp1ABVYBep3bOQkaNIACC8EQ2JA6ogb8wJJaGYEYMH0UTsosUy8gm-LTGshggWBtTRpO0FRIsyxIGsQK7nIHrUrS+wgABQQfl+JA-hq-6AZWuZFg4xEkmcJbIGWzTaLR1YcIxzG1mCcwrFWcjti227bPu8pHtAJCYDwAi6uox6nuel7HA6d4PiUzgvvUZEQN+v7UUBEYANosZBU4NgJAC6CFCZwZkJhB3KWTB07WThT6cPhD5dmc-mOeB0Zod41mkZ++kUYZAFQJxZT0SxDRNBWj5cRwnR1khHJNvZolVtKVZgl25K9C4AB6AC0FVIKkXRZIRwDVE5KGfK56GNsKoripKhWlbmWR1Q1TVBf4qFZRhnVuN1u64ZwXZHKcFxXAO9xPK87yzF8Y1CsCmXzoungrmuPVibuEmHsg+DSbJ8mYA6SlntgF5Xup97EPVWlVjpyB6QZVExQ0pnma1IXZeMtkGEDzWjS5oMTR5s0cN9SAHHSDRVP5ZyMVA4XkZRf4xUUZh2FNEqec48DEFAi4+kEqOSOjw3If4oNEyTbTtAl0OsclLSpWlGVglZOVtpsiMlUNEvlVVNWDV2wMMnDHUiqTPVyGC1YDfV8vc2NVmAl1EqI0NC29sttyrSOG2tZmzJTjts69PtS5Heu2xrEAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the research effort and the cleanness of your examples  Better than documentation!

Answer (score 1):

It properly correlate the parameters when they are bound together in an object.

```
function myFn3({valueType,value}:{valueType: 'a', value: '1'}): any
function myFn3({valueType,value}:{valueType: 'b', value: '2'}): any
function myFn3({valueType,value}:{valueType: 'a', value: '1'}|{valueType: 'b', value: '2'}): any {
    if (valueType === 'a') {
        value // value: "1"
    }
}
```

```
function myFn<
    T extends {valueType: 'a', value: '1'}|{valueType: 'b', value: '2'}
>(
    {valueType,value}:{valueType: 'a', value: '1'}|{valueType: 'b', value: '2'}
) {
    if (valueType === 'a') {
        let x = value; // value:"1"
    }
}
```

[TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DEwGYAUBvANwEMAbEAUwBVUAHcgGmLPIF8AuQ0i6utxAciL96iJhT78AjPxYBKPkTCoAsAChQkWAhQZs+MVVoMD7Tsx7kJAI2GiulgQCYZ8xIpXrw0eEjSZcZtxGjPamBhYSQiIGEtIsAD6BhrwCNtH2Es5yCkqIeGqIhYgwwIg44UaIALw1AkKyeQVFzQaIAPRtdsx8AESSPU2FLGrDnpo+OpgAPIOIlIjkAB5Q5GAAJgDOeRUpgrYxAnGJOw78aV3iTjJqAHw4s0kWIcxh9hF1+xmHMsdvRtafbpXUYNfKqZolMonaq1Pag2bNEjkKCIRbVC7kADc7U6MT6A3BRVGoyAA)

Comment: Obviously in your original posted form, the correlated type could be resolved in theory, but the current implementation of TypeScript just does not do it - it is not a bug it is working as expected.  If you want to submit it as a proposal first you must check for any similar proposals, and if there is nothing then write it up.

Comment: As for your overloads case, the code could infer the correlation by referencing the overload declarations, but currently does not.